# In PCB DFM process; manufacturer have highlighted Gullwing Issue. What is Gullwing?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication

[image: Gullwing Issue]

In PCB DFM process; manufacturer have highlighted Gullwing issue saying "Gullwing is not optimal robust SMT process.

What is "Gullwing"?

Answer (score 3):

Gull Wing packages are a kind of package lead configurations as can be seen below.
The GullWing package is depictured in image (a). If there is a problem with the DFM process regarding Gull Wings, I would suggest looking at the component and see if the datasheet recommend a landing pattern / solder mask layout and see if your design is compatible with that. It might be that the way it is designed now will not lead to an optimal solder joint and therefor reliability.

[image]

*Image from: Reflow Soldering Processes and Troubleshooting: SMT, BGA, CSP, and Flip Chip Technologies by Ning-Cheng Lee*

Answer (score 0):

The **real** gull wing ICs had long (often golden) leads:
[image]

In your case it looks like they gave the name to SMD pins you find on TSSOP, TQFP etc. packages.

Looking at your footprint it looks rather long and a bit wide for the pin. This may make that the chip starts to 'float' during soldering. As Remco Vink says: look at the datasheet for the recommended landing pattern.